# Missing Appcelerator Module - appcelerator.https

Tags: android, module, titanium, appcelerator

Where can I find the appcelerator.https module? All Git links are no longer available (404), and I need SSL Certification for an HTTP request. I found a copy (v1.1.3) in the forums, but I am having issues with this version and want to see if any updated versions address my issue. I can see v1.1.4 and v2.0.1 exist, but I can't seem to find them anywhere!

Says v1.1.4 and v2.0.1 exist:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/MOD-2293?jql=project%20%3D%20MOD%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%22https%201.1.4%22

Original link to get the module that gives a 404 error:
https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/appcelerator.https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [https documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Https) there is a note:

> This feature requires a Pro, Team, or Enterprise subscription.

If you have one of those subscriptions (or maybe indie subscription as well? idk), you can log in to [platform.appcelerator.com](https://platform.appcelerator.com), click your profile in the upper-right, and select Downloads.  There should be a list of modules available including https.

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy looking everywhere for this!